# Confusion regarding session in JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf-2

I have a confusion regarding session valid. I read that session belongs to browser not to tabs. Means if you open a browser and open your hotmail account, then close the browser, and then again open it, you have to logged in again. But if you open the browser and open your hotmail in new tab and then close the tab and then again open the hotmail in new tab then you are already login. But in maintaining session i am encountering something very confusing. Java has a check for valid session like

```
/**
 * Each time user closes the browser then this will become null, but then onwards it always
 * has value, which is called cliendId
 */
String sessionID = httpServletRequest.getRequestedSessionId();

/**
 * Each time user close the tab or browser or session expires automatically this will
 * become false
 */
boolean sessionValid = httpServletRequest.isRequestedSessionIdValid();
```

**getRequestedSessionId()** is fine. When you open your website first time then it is null but then it always has the same value. Indicating that user is using the same browser. Fine. But **isRequestedSessionIdValid()** is very confusing to me. when-ever i close the tab then it become null. Why it is getting null? why my session is not valid if i close the tab? Do i need to set something in my web.xml file to tell java that do not expire session on tab closing?

Thank you.

Comment: A `boolean` can impossibly be `null`. This is definitely confusing :)

Comment: oh yes BalusC:) i mean it become false(angel).  Why it become false on closing tabs? :)

Comment: Closing the tab should not send a request. How exactly are you opening a new tab? Aren't you actually closing the entire browser?

Comment: No i just open a new tab with ctrl+t. And i close the tab. Actually i am using netbeans so what i do, i run the project in debug mode, and i put breakpoint  in my filter class. So whenever i close the tab and then again run the priject, this condition become true which indicates session expire `if (sessionID != null && !sessionValid) {..}`. If i close the entire browser then this condition become true `if (sessionID == null && !sessionValid){}`. Actually when you open the website first time then you come into `sessionID = null`, but then each time you close the tab you come into the first one.

Comment: I want to ask if session related to browser then why it comes to condition `if (sessionID != null && !sessionValid) {}`. If session is related to tab then it's ok. Each time you close the tab your session expires. But then this thing confuses me that if you login with hotmail and then close the tab, and then enter the url of your hotmail, then you are login. I am confused...